# Show that the inverse of function $f$ is one to one

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I have Mathematics IV class. I need to prove that inverses of all functions is an one to one function. I cannot do anything. Is there anybody can help me?

$f(x) = y \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x)$ is a one to one function?

Comment: Inverses are defined iff the function in question is bijective.

Comment: What is the definition of inverse function you are using?

Comment: If $f:A\rightarrow B$ has an inverse, then $f$ is a bijection. This means that there is a bijective function $f^{-1}:B\rightarrow A$. A bijection is both an surjection and an injection (one-to-one).

Comment: The inverse of $f^{-1}(x)$ is $f(x)$. Since only one-to-one functions have inverses, $f^{-1}(x)$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:A  \to B$ be a function. Suppose that the inverse function $g:B \to A$ is noninjective. Sso there exist $b_1 \neq b_2 \in B$ so that $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$. Then $f$ is not well defined since $f \circ g(b_1) \neq f \circ g(b_2)$, meaning that one element gets mapped to two different places.

This is a failure of the "vertical line test" in elementary calculus if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a bijective function. Then for every $y\in Y$ there exists a unique element $x_y\in X$ such that $f(x_y)=y$. One can then define a new function $f^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X:y\mapsto x_y$. Clearly one has that $f\circ f^{-1}=Id_Y$ and $f^{-1}\circ f=Id_X$. The goal is to show that $f^{-1}$ is bijective as well.

Suppose that $f^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(y')$, by applying $f$ to this equalty we get that $y=y'$, hence $f^{-1}$ is injective. Now choose $x\in X$, then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$, hence $f^{-1}$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : E \to F$  be a function. If $f^{-1}$ exists, then by definition :

$\forall x \in E,  f^{-1}(f(x)) = x $ and $\forall y \in F,f(f^{-1}(y)) = x   $

From there you can easily show that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both "one to one or more" AND "one to one or less" which is "one to one".

Comment: What in the world does "one to one or more/less" mean?

Comment: Haha "one to one or more" for surjective and "one to one or less" for injective.
It was my attempt to be understood by the author since he used "one to one" which I assume means bijective.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a little more general statement:

> **Lemma.** Let $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ functions. Then
>
> $a)$ if $g\circ f$ is injective, so is $f$,
>
> $b)$ if $g\circ f$ is surjective, so is $g$.

Now, assuming $f\colon A\to B$ is invertible, we have that there exists $g\colon B\to A$ such that $g\circ f = \operatorname{id}_A$, $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_B$, but then by $a)$ $g$ is injective since $\operatorname{id}_B$ is, which answers your question.

*Proof of Lemma.* I will prove $a)$ and encourage you to prove $b)$ as an exercise. Let $x,y\in A$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. Then $(g\circ f)(x) = (g\circ f)(y)$ which implies $x = y$ since $g\circ f$ is injective. This proves that $f$ is injective as well.

But, since we are here, let's mention a very useful proposition as well:

> **Proposition.** Function $f\colon A\to B$ is invertible if and only if it is bijective.

Before the proof, let's see how this answers your question. Assume that $f\colon A\to B$ is invertible, i.e. there exists $g\colon B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$, $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_B$. But then $g$ is invertible as well and hence by our proposition bijective.

*Proof of the Proposition.* Assume that $f$ is bijective. That means that for any $b\in B$ there is unique $a\in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. Define $g\colon B\to A$ with $g(b) = a$. Then for any $a\in A$, $g(f(a)) = a$ by definition of $g$ and we have $f(g(b)) = f(a) = b$, for all $b\in B$, i.e. $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$ and $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_B$. Hence, $f$ is invertible with $g$ its inverse.

For the other direction, use the Lemma.